# Finding the shortest distance between two angles

Tags: c#

I've been trying to find a way of finding the shortest distance between two angles. The angles are in the interval -360 < 360 and are given in degrees.

In short, i need a simple way (the simpler the better) to find the shortest distance between two angles, let's call them angle1 and angle2. Angle1 is the angle i want to get to, angle 2 is the angle i am at. After this i want to use an if function to determine the rotation direction of an entity.

Pseudocode:

```c#
CloseDistance = (Find shortest distance between angle1 (where i want to go) and angle2 (where i am))

if (CloseDistance > Something)
  {Rotate to the right} else {Rotate to the left}
```

Comment: By distance you mean the smallest angle to rotate by to get from one heading to another, correct?

Comment: I don't quite understand what "shortest distance between two angles" means. Angles are scalars, so the shortest "distance" between them is just their difference. If you're talking about some other form of geometric distance, it would be helpful if you made a rough diagram.

Comment: Got a fix in the form of the answer by Kyle, thanks for the help!

Comment: Asad: Say you have two angles, 47 degrees and 229 degrees. Their difference is 182 degrees... but they're on a circle, meaning there are two distances between them: 182 and 178. The OP is asking how to get the shorter of the two.Personally, if the difference is > 180, I just subtract it from 360.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
public static double AngleDifference( double angle1, double angle2 )
{
    double diff = ( angle2 - angle1 + 180 ) % 360 - 180;
    return diff < -180 ? diff + 360 : diff;
}
```

This works by noticing that we want to take the difference between the two angles, `angle1` and `angle2` and wrap that result to the range [-180, 179).  The mod operator allows us to wrap something to the range [0, n).  I.e. `x % n` "wraps" (with a caveat for `x < 0`) x to the range [0, n).

Our range starts at -180 rather than 0, so we shift it over by adding 180.  Then we wrap to 360, then we shift back.  That's what the first line of the method does.

The second line takes care of that little wrinkle with negative numbers.  If `angle2 - angle1 + 180` happened to be less than 0, then `diff` will be less than -180.  In that case we just wrap it back into range by adding 360 to it.  Otherwise we do nothing.

As an added bonus, the input angles are completely unconstrained.  They need not be between -360 and 360.  They can be anything.

Comment: Implemented this into my code, works flawlessly and does exactly what i need it to. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Captain No problem!  Please consider selecting this answer since it helped you.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you need result angle in interval -180..+179. Negative signs means right rotation, positive means left (or vice versa).

Ergo, you need the [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) with modulo 360.

In C# [remaidner operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244368(v=vs.60).aspx) does what you need:

```
var distance = (destinationAngle - sourceAngle) % 360;
```

Unfortunately it gives result in interval -359..+359. To correct this you can transform too large values to interval -180..+179:

```
var distance = (destinationAngle - sourceAngle) % 360;
if (distance < -180)
    distance += 360;
else if (distance > 179)
    distance -= 360;
```

Asymmetric ends of interval (-180 and +179) have appeared because -180 and +180 both are the same angle, so you should choose one of them to avoid ambiguity.

F.e.

```
   Destination | Source | Result
            45 |     30 |     15
            30 |     45 |    -15
           -45 |    -30 |    -15
           -30 |    -45 |     15
360 + 45 = 405 |     30 |     15
          -405 |    -30 |    -15
```

As I can see it what you need. If your angles are doubles, use [Math.IEEERemainder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.math.ieeeremainder(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my Python version which I find easier to explain:

```
def smallestAngle(currentAngle, targetAngle) -> int:
    # Subtract the angles, constraining the value to [0, 360)
    diff = ( targetAngle - currentAngle) % 360

    # If we are more than 180 we're taking the long way around.
    # Let's instead go in the shorter, negative direction
    if diff > 180 :
        diff = -(360 - diff)
    return diff
```

Beware that some systems' modulo functions return negative values and will not work! If you are using Javascript, here is a modulo function you seek:

```
// Javascript always-positive modulo function
const mod = (n, m) => ((n % m) + m) % m
```

I was asked to show this in C# so here you go...

```
public static double smallestAngle(double currentAngle, double targetAngle)
{
    double diff = (targetAngle - currentAngle) % 360;
    return diff <= 180 ? diff : -(360 - diff);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The question was tagged with C#. Please try to provide solution proposal in that language.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum distance between 2 angles is 180 degrees, just pick an angle that is between 0 and 360

```
int angle1 = n;
int angle2 = n2;

if(angle1 < 0)
   angle1 += 360;

if(angle2 < 0)
   angle2 += 360;

if (angle2 > angle1 && angle2 - angle1 <= 180 )
   //go clockwise
else if (angle2 > angle1 && angle2 - angle1 > 180 )
   //go counter clockwise
else if (angle1 > angle2 && angle1 - angle2 <= 180 )
   //go counter clockwise
else if (angle1 > angle2 && angle1 - angle2 > 180 )
   //go clockwise
```

Answer (score 1):

The Simplest way I found is

```
double closedistance = (destangle - startangle) % 360
```

`abs(closedistance)` gives you the required distance.

sign of closedistance (`= closedistance/abs(closedistance)`) gives the direction of rotation (+ anticlockwise, - clockwise) or just check it like this

```
if (closedistance > 0) {} // anticlockwise
else {} // clockwise
```

This works for any value of angles.

Answer (score 0):

I found the most suitable solution in an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110080/shortest-way-to-achieve-target-angle)

I am also using array to store the last two angles - I am doing that because I receive a new angle every second (via external source).
It is written in Swift but can be easily transformed for any other language

```
if angleArray.count > 1 {
                                                
//prepare the two angles
let sourceAngle = angleArray[0]
let targetAngle = angleArray[1]
                                                
//get all three different distances
let alpha = targetAngle - sourceAngle
let beta = targetAngle - sourceAngle + 360
let gamma = targetAngle - sourceAngle - 360

//get the lowest one value by absolute value
var A = min(abs(alpha), abs(beta), abs(gamma))
//get the proper sign - plus or minus
switch A {
case abs(alpha):
A = alpha
case abs(beta):
A = beta
default:
A = gamma
}
//add it to the source angle
let newAngle = sourceAngle + A
//remove the last element of the array
angleArray.remove(at: 1)
return newAngle
}
```

It works flawlessly in my app where I represent wind and heading values which change a lot around the 0/360 overlap region.