# Compass & Anemometer Unusual Behaviour - Swift UI

Tags: swiftui, navigation, rotation, logic

I am getting crazy the last few days and I can't solve that issue. I am making an app that contains anemometer and compass and they share the same issue.
I will share only for the anemometer here just as an example.
So, I have a wind sensor and I get data updated every second for the wind direction & speed and everything works well until .... it reaches a transition from 1 degree to 359 or vice versa. This is not the natural behaviour of the anemometer.
I have tried many different solutions from internet and stack overflow but nothing seems to work. Here I post two solutions - first one is ok for the transition between degrees around 0 but it does the same thing when it hits 180 limit.
The second method I tried to capture two angles, and save the values in an array. Then I calculate the shortest distance between the angles and apply the difference to the first angle and try to rotate in the relevant direction but it doesn't work as well.
Any good solutions?

Please see video here:
[anemometer_going_crazy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkt3f.gif)

Here is the code - I do the calculations here in the matt manager and once calculated I just call the View with this value "windAngle"

```
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceiveMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
        if let str = message.string { // <--- here or something like this
            print(str)
            let strSplit = str.split(separator: ",")
            
            windAngle = Double(strSplit[1])!
            
//            //MARK: Solution 1
//
//            if windAngle <= 180 {
//
//                windAngle = windAngle
//                print(windAngle)
//            } else {
//                windAngle = -(360 - windAngle)
//                print(windAngle)
//            }
            //MARK: - Solution 2
//            windArray.append(windAngle)
//            print(windArray.count)
//            //kind of calibration
//            if windArray.count > 2 {
//
//                let diff1 = windArray[2] - windArray[1]
//                let diff2 = -(360 - windArray[2] - windArray[1])
//                print(windArray[1])
//                print(windArray[2])
//
//                print(diff1)
//                print(diff2)
//
//
//                if (diff1.magnitude <= diff2.magnitude) {
//                    windAngle = windArray[1] + diff1
//                } else {
//                    windAngle = windArray[1] + diff2
//                }
//
//                windArray[1] = windArray[2]
//                windArray.removeLast()
//            }

            windSpeed = Double(strSplit[3])!
        }
        
    }
```

EDIT: 1
so, first I had a mistake in the code because the two modulus differences were not equal to 360, which I corrected but yet not a good result;

```
                let diff1 = windArray[2] - windArray[1]
                let diff2 = -(windArray[2] - windArray[1] + 360) // <-- correction here
                print("first wind angle: \(windArray[1])")
                print("next wind angle: \(windArray[2])")

                print("first path difference: \(diff1)")
                print("second path diference: \(diff2)")
```

So, if you see the values circled in red it is obvious that the algorithm works until the point that it chooses the path with the proper length but it just takes the opposite sign and instead of decreasing the angle it decreases it by the difference or just makes something stupid. I am almost sure that I don't do the calculation for the two different path in a correct way but I just don't see it :)
Another pair of eyes would definitely help :)

[values_from_wind_sensors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah43Q.png)

Comment: maybe all you have to do is to normalize your `windAngle` to be always between 0...360 with
 a function like: `func norm(_ x: Double) -> Double {
 var y = fmod(x, 360.0)
 if y < 0 { y += 360 }
 return y
}`
 Can you show some of the values you get in your `windAngle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, after some more time spent on research I found the right solution, at least for me. I will post it here in case somebody needs it.
Thanks to that answer: [shortest_path_between_angles_calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28036652/finding-the-shortest-distance-between-two-angles)

answered by Kyle, which I believe is the most elegant, I found the way of how to calculate the shortest path between two angles and return a correct value with a correct sign.

The idea is that after the job has been done and angle has been used to be published in the view, I assign it to the first element of my array for future reference when calculating next angle. In that way the -180 / 180 range is shifting together with the angle and the view never goes crazy or overlaping. The same principle goes for the compass and I used it there too.
Here is the code:

```
//MARK: - Calculating the wind angle
            //add next wind angle for calculation
            windArray.append(windAngle)
            
            if windArray.count > 1 {
                //calculating the differnece between the two angles
                let diff = (windArray[1] - windArray[0] + 180).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360) - 180
                //getting the shortest path to the next angle
                let correctedDiff = diff < -180 ? diff + 360 : diff
                //assigning the final value to the windAngle that is going called in the main view
                windAngle = windArray[0] + correctedDiff

                //once the job is done assign the last wind angle to the [0] element of the array
                //for a future reference point
                windArray[0] = windAngle
                //remove the last angle and prepare the array for the next angle
                windArray.remove(at: 1)
            }
```